# How i can convert to version 3?

Tags: pine-script

Hello How i can convert to version 3?

```
study(shorttitle = "MACD 4C", title = "4 colour MACD")
fastMA = input(title="Fast moving average", type = integer, defval = 12, minval = 7)
slowMA = input(title="Slow moving average", type = integer, defval = 26, minval = 7)
lastColor = yellow
[currMacd,_,_] = macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
[prevMacd,_,_] = macd(close[1], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
plotColor = currMacd > 0 
    ? currMacd > prevMacd ? lime : green 
    : currMacd < prevMacd ? maroon : red
plot(currMacd, style = histogram, color = plotColor, linewidth = 3)
plot(0, title = "Zero line", linewidth = 1, color = gray)
```

I wanted to try the trading view's own flip feature, but I couldn't find it. Had to change it manually.

Comment: [Here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html) is your guide. The auto converter tool is available for v3 and above.

Comment: This indicator was written with version 1. For this reason, the automatic converter cannot be used.

Comment: That's what I said. You need to convert it to v3 yourself then you can use the auto converter tool.

Comment: I do not have the necessary code knowledge to do this, I need help.

Answer (score 0):

This will actually work in version 3 without (almost) any changes. You just need to add `//version=3` to the beginning of the script. You also have a minor line break issue, which might be a copy-paste thing:

```
//@version=3
study(shorttitle = "MACD 4C", title = "4 colour MACD")
fastMA = input(title="Fast moving average", type = integer, defval = 12, minval = 7)
slowMA = input(title="Slow moving average", type = integer, defval = 26, minval = 7)
lastColor = yellow
[currMacd,_,_] = macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
[prevMacd,_,_] = macd(close[1], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
plotColor = currMacd > 0 
     ? currMacd > prevMacd ? lime : green 
     : currMacd < prevMacd ? maroon : red
plot(currMacd, style = histogram, color = plotColor, linewidth = 3)
plot(0, title = "Zero line", linewidth = 1, color = gray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use V3, nor V4 version for pinescript as they are outdated.
Here is the V5 version of your code :

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle='MACD 4C', title='4 colour MACD')
fastMA = input.int(title='Fast moving average', defval=12, minval=7)
slowMA = input.int(title='Slow moving average', defval=26, minval=7)
lastColor = color.yellow
[currMacd, _, _] = ta.macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
[prevMacd, _, _] = ta.macd(close[1], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
plotColor = currMacd > 0 ? currMacd > prevMacd ? color.lime : color.green : currMacd < prevMacd ? color.maroon : color.red
plot(currMacd, style=plot.style_histogram, color=plotColor, linewidth=3)
plot(0, title='Zero line', linewidth=1, color=color.new(color.gray, 0))
```

Comment: But how can i add buy and sell signal to this indicator?

Comment: @byGEREN your code was a 'study' , which is an 'indicator' in V5. An indicator is not a strategy, you can use buy/sell order with an indicaor. If my answer did convert correctly your code, please accept my answer. If your want to transform this code in a strategy (to use buy/sell order), please ask a new question, you will get help

Comment: @byGEREN there is a mistake in my comment : I wanted to write : you can't use buy/sell order with an indicator